# I am unable to delete the SharePoint online subsite that is created under the team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, sub-site, team-sites

[image]

I am unable to delete the SharePoint online subsite that is created under the team site.

Please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Remove-SPOSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps) cmdlet is used to send a SharePoint Online **site collection** to the SharePoint Online Recycle Bin & **not subsite**.

To delete SharePoint online subsite:

1. Use PnP PowerShell [Remove-PnPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpweb?view=sharepoint-ps) cmdlet

   **OR**
2. Follow the steps given at: [SharePoint Online: Delete a Subsite using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/05/sharepoint-online-delete-subsite-using-powershell.html)